# Как при нажатии кнопки radio, автоматически нажать на submit?

Tags: html

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать при нажатии на кнопку радио автоматически включалась кнопка субмит в одной форме.

````
<input onclick="vibor_pay(2)" type="radio" value="<?=$id?>" class="radio" id="radio" />
    
    <label for="radio">Согласен</label>
    
                        <br><br>
                        <input id="subm" type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"style= "background-color: green; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 21px;" value="Продолжить" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="type_payment" value="<?=$type_payment?>">
                        </form>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое с jQuery:

```
$('#radio').click(function(){
    $('#subm').click()
})
```

Comment: Спасибо blizzart.

Comment: Немного доработал свой код, все работает хорошо. Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: Рад, что помог! Код топорный , зато boilerplate, чтобы не отлаживать) Хотя можно было на $('#radio') вместо клик повесить .change, чтобы при нажатие на лейбл тоже срабатывал.